# store to CoreData from other viewController doesn't work

Tags: uitableview, core-data, entity-relationship

I am new in CoreData and i have one question.
I've created project where are two TableViews and i have two entities with one to many relationships.
My app work fine when i have just this two TableView's and when i add new objects right in this TableView's. But if i add one more ViewController with push segue from my second "detail" TableView and want to add some new objects to that TableView it doesn't work.

here is my code for my ViewController adding method :

```
- (void)addItem:(id)sender {
Entity2 *second = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity2"  inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[second setName:nameTextField.text];
[second setHowMany:howManyTextField.text];
second.entity1 = self.firstEntity ;

[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

and here is my detail TableView code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
Entity2*second = [self.firstEntity.entity2.allObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = second.name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = second.howMany;
return cell;
}
```

Have someone any idea what should i do?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Check if managed object context is nil.

Comment: when i put NSLog after i store that data, my result is <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x8d88d20>
also there is that object, but don't know why isn't in my table.

Comment: Did you reload the table (e.g. with `[tableView reloadData];`)?

Comment: yes. i have there viewWillAppear method and there is [self.tableview reloadData];

Comment: Your code looks fine (edit - not after you posted the second code snippet). Check the store via the `sqlite3` command line tool, or SQLite Manager - is it saved or not? If yes, it is your table (maybe you have a fetched results controller and need to call `performFetch`), otherwise catch the save error and investigate.

Comment: I have downloaded some SQlite from web, but cant open my .xcdatamodeld file with that. Any suggestion ?

Comment: when i put NSLog and check my entities, both are <null> also that view controller doesn't know from where index path i want to store that data.

Comment: i got it. I have to insert prepareForSegue method from my tableViewController to my ViewController, because in other case that viewController doesn't know, where he should store that data.

Comment: Great - so my first assessment was correct. Please consider accepting the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably did not pass your managed object context correctly to the new view controller. Make sure that in `prepareForSegue` you pass the context

```
NewViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```